# How can I check That Every values of an numpy.ndarray are all the same in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, artificial-intelligence, streamlit

Trying to make a basic hand-digit recognition AI and I just want the AI to not make a prediction when the canvas is empty, I basically tried everything I could but most of the time facing the "unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" error.
Found this solution that doesn't make an error but didn't work for me

```
canvas_result = st_canvas(
fill_color="rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3)",  # Fixed fill color with some opacity
stroke_width=8,
stroke_color='#FFFFFF',
background_color='#000000',
height=250,
width=250,
drawing_mode='freedraw',
key="canvas",
)

array = canvas_result.image_data

if array is not None: # HERE

  if prediction is None:
      if streamlit is None:
          streamlit = resize(
            (np.dot(array[..., :3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])) / 255, (28, 28))

      width, height, *_ = streamlit.shape
      prediction = streamlit.reshape(1, width, height, 1)
      prediction = prediction.astype('float32')
```

this gives me:
[canvas empty but still a prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QanES.png)

I tried to convert my numpy dictionary to usefull values but didn't succeeded

EDIT: canvas_result.image_data is an object that looks like

```
([[[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  ...
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]
 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255] ...)
```

describing the image as the rgb color and the possible range of the 3 color so I can't really check if they are all null as 255 is here

so I tried

```
if np.max(array[..., :3]) != np.min(array[..., :3]):
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if np.all(array == 0):
```

or

```
if len(np.unique(array)) == 1:
```

Comment: neither of them worked (no prediction at all even when I draw something) @richardec

Comment: @richardec 's solutions are correct. In the first instance if all values are 0 then the expression is true. in the second if there is only one unique value (i.e all elements are the same) then the expression evaluates to true. I think your logic may be backwards you would have to negate the `if` with `not` in order to to skip executing when the canvas is empty.

Comment: @BradDay the fact that nothing appear in both cases means that the if statement return the same value wether or not  there is nomething on the canvas if I add a not to negate the whole things this is not helpful as I will get a prediction in both cases